# How to get the result of another method from another method and print it

Tags: java, methods

i want to get all the result from another method and compile it as one

```
package labexer1a;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabExer1A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        faveNumber();
        faveCartChar();
        mI();
        fullName();
        nickName();
    }
    public static void faveNumber() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Type your Number: ");
        int faveNumber = s.nextInt();
    }
    public static void faveCartChar() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Type your favorite Cartoon or Anime Character: ");
        String faveCartChar = s.next();
    }
    public static void mI() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Type your Middle Initial: ");
        String mI = s.next();
    }
    public static void fullName() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Type your FullName: ");
        String fullName = s.next();
    }
    public static void nickName() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Type your Nickname: ");
        String nickName = s.next();
    }
    public static void result() {
        System.out.print(faveNumber + "is my favorite number");
        System.out.print("I love" + faveCartChar);
        System.out.print("My name is" + fullName);
        System.out.print("You can call me" + nickName);
    }
}
```

Comment: i see so what am i going to do? im new to java tbh

Comment: you can see that i create a multiple method and im trying to get all the result from those method and print it one by one

Comment: the output should look like this 
23 is my favorite number
I love Rick
My name is test1 test1
You can call me Test

Comment: is other way to make it simple for me tbh i really hate separating method and doing the same code again

Comment: Return a value from the methods, instead of declaring them as `void`. Also, create one `Scanner` in your `main` method and pass it into them as a parameter, instead of creating scanners over and over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the fuctions return type from `void` to `String` or `int` for example and the return the result.

Example:

```java
public static String fullName() {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Type your FullName: ");
    String fullName = s.next();
    return fullName;
}

public static int faveNumber() {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Type your Number: ");
    int faveNumber = s.nextInt();
    return faveNumber;
}
```

If you now want to acces the data just call the fuction and it will return it.

Example:

```java
System.out.println(nickName() + " is my favorite number");
System.out.println("You can call me " + faveNumber());
```

And also I would recomend naming the functions more like `getNickName` so anyone can direclty see that it will return the nick name!